# ToList (Linq) doesn't appear to copy references

Tags: c#, linq, list, reference, ienumerable

I have code that looks something like this:

```
var selectedItems = ItemList.SelectedItems().ToList();
var selectedItems2 = ItemList2.SelectedItems().ToList();
selectedItems[0] = selectedItems2[0];
```

Here's a look at the `SelectedItems` extension method:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> SelectedItems<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source) where T : ISelectable
{
    return source.Where(s => s.IsSelected);
}
```

Whenever I do a `ReferenceEquals(ItemList, selectedItems)`, the value returns `false` and whenever I modify a value within any of the lists, the changes aren't reflected in the other list.

The Items in the `ItemList` are reference types (custom made classes).

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

Here's the original code. I didn't want to overcomplicate things but here it is nonetheless:

```
var test = Map.TileMap.Layers[0].TileList.SelectedItems().ToList();
if (ReferenceEquals(test[0], Map.TileMap.Layers[0].TileList[0]))
{
           // returns true     
}

var tileset2D = Tileset.TileMap.Layers[0].TileList.SelectedItems().To2D(t => t.SelectableRegion.Y).ToList();
test[0] = tileset2D[0][0];

// test[0] has changed but Tileset.TileMap.Layers[0].TileList[0] hasn't changed.
```

Here's the To2D extension method:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> To2D<T, TKey>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, TKey> keySelector)
{
    if (source == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source), "Source collection cannot be null");
    }

    return source.GroupBy(keySelector);
}
```

Comment: What is the source of `ItemList`? `IQueryable`/`List<T>`/etc.?

Comment: List<T>. T is ISelectable.

Comment: Almost sounds like that list is constructed from different entities already. Are you sure that `ReferenceEquals(ItemList[0], ItemList2[0]) == true` before the filtering?

Answer (score 1):

Calling `.ToList()` isn't a casting operation. It generates a brand new list object and populates it with the results of the enumerable prior to `.ToList()`. The references aren't the same because they are different lists.

The `SelectedItems` method should be returning instances of the original list. So you should be able to test that it works.

With this sample code:

```
var ItemList = new List<Selectable>()
{
    new Selectable() { IsSelected = true },
    new Selectable() { IsSelected = false },
};

var selectedItems = ItemList.SelectedItems().ToList();

Console.WriteLine(selectedItems[0].IsSelected);

ItemList[0].IsSelected = false;

Console.WriteLine(selectedItems[0].IsSelected);
```

I get the results:

```
True
False
```

My implementation of `Selectable` is:

```
public class Selectable : ISelectable
{
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}
```

You must have something happening in code you haven't shown.

---

You've added some more code, and now the snippit `.GroupBy(t => t.SelectableRegion.Y)` makes me think that the grouping isn't working as expected. You should test your assumptions about what the grouping key returns

My suggestion, at this point, is that you avoid recreating extension methods. It would be better to write `source.Where(s => s.IsSelected).GroupBy(t => t.SelectableRegion.Y)` than `source.SelectedItems().To2D(t => t.SelectableRegion.Y)`. This kind of thing just confuses the code and makes it harder to reason about. The kinds of errors you're experience surface far too often.

Comment: But shouldn't it copy the references from the previous list?

Comment: because ToList() returns new List<T>(source)

Comment: @Enigmativity How do I return instances of the original list? Isn't that what I'm doing by using Where?

Comment: That shouldn't affect anything though. I'm using the value of the GroupBy to assign to my List. Even if I do something like Map.TileMap.Layers[0].TileList[0] = Tileset.TileMap.Layers[0].TileList[0]     that still doesn't work. test[0] doesn't match Map.TileMap.Layers[0].TileList[0] even though they have the same reference. Also when I assign a value to say test[0], the reference changes and is no longer equal to Map.TileMap.Layers[0].TileList[0]

Comment: Ok, I did a quick test and my hunch was correct. I did this: Map.TileMap.Layers[0].TileList[0].Texture = Tileset.TileMap.Layers[0].TileList[0].Texture; and it worked! So therefore whenever I just assign the whole value, there reference is being changed. Hmm

Comment: Now that I think about it. It's expected behaviour. By doing Map.TileMap.Layers[0].TileList[0] = Tileset.TileMap.Layers[0].TileList[0]; I'm assigning the reference of Tileset.TileMap.Layers[0].TileList[0] to Map.TileMap.Layers[0].TileList[0].

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! I can't believe the answer was right in front of me but I couldn't see it. That's what I get for staying up till 5 in the morning coding xD

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was assigning a new reference to my list item

```
test[0] = tileset2D[0][0];
```

So now test[0] is point to the same address in memory as tileset2D[0][0]. That's why the values in test[0] weren't modifying values inside Map.TileMap.Layers[0].TileList.

So I basically have to create some time of DeepClone method that will copy the values and clone the references without assigning a new reference to my TileList item.

Thanks for all the help :)